# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/ResponseErrorHandler

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku, httpwebresponse

I got this issue when I tried to open my deployed application in **HEROKU**. NoClassDefFoundError is being thrown for the Spring Framework class ResponseErrorHandler. I tried changing the xml and properties files, but in vain.

> [33m2014-12-15T12:12:46.641119+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Starting process with command `java -Dserver.port=39847 -Ddatabase.url=postgres://genreimfcnjetj:Swt7eGbTANi2-X7tBru0wTX4GT@ec2-54-235-76-206.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d9108hum0pg29o -Xss512k -XX:+UseCompressedOops -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar target/*.jar`
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.517755+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.518480+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3035)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.517563+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Exception in thread "main" **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/client/ResponseErrorHandler**
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.518545+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3005)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.519084+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.319339+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx384m  -Djava.rmi.server.useCodebaseOnly=true
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.519022+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.518428+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.518938+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1771)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.519224+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.520145+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.519277+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.519388+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.520395+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.520237+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.519339+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.520312+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:47.520441+00:00 app[web.1]:←[0m   ... 7 more
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:48.201159+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m Process exited with status 1
>   [33m2014-12-15T12:12:48.209235+00:00 heroku[web.1]:←[0m State changed from starting to crashed

Can I have some HELP please.

Sharing my classes relating to ResponseErrorHandler.

**CustomerErrorResponseHandler.java**

```
package rentitnew;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler;
import org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler;

class CustomResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
private ResponseErrorHandler errorHandler = new DefaultResponseErrorHandler();

@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
    return errorHandler.hasError(response);
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse response) throws IOException {
}
}
```

**Application.java**

```
package rentitnew;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

@Autowired
private WebMvcProperties mvcProperties = new WebMvcProperties();
@Autowired
Credentials credentials;
@Autowired
ClientHttpRequestFactory basicSecure;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    RestTemplate _restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    _restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    _restTemplate.setErrorHandler(new CustomResponseErrorHandler());
    _restTemplate.setRequestFactory(basicSecure);
    return _restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory() {
    return new BasicSecureSimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
}

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(locations = "classpath:META-INF/integration/credentials.yml")
public Credentials getCredentials() {
    return new Credentials();
}

public static class Credentials {
    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> credentials = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getCredentials() {
        return this.credentials;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>rentitnew</groupId>
<artifactId>rentitnew</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>rentitnew</name>
<description>Rentit Project</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.springtestdbunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.14.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
        <version>0.16.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>rentitnew.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                <systemProperty>
                    <name>spring.profiles.active</name>
                    <value>production</value>
                </systemProperty>
                <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
                <reportsDirectory>shippable/testresults</reportsDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                    <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7.2</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**Procfile**

```
web: java -Dserver.port=$PORT -Ddatabase.url=$DATABASE_URL $JAVA_OPTS -Dspring.profiles.active=production -jar target/*.jar
```

Can I have some suggestions how I can change the code/other files so that I can open my application.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I see I haven't answered this question yet. So even though it is late, I will provide the fix I had made to solve this issue.

Apart from the change proposed by Jens, I added the following plugin into the plugins tag in `pom.xml`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

I had accidently removed this plugin from `pom.xml` which caused the issue above.

Answer (score 3):

You miss the `org.springframework.web` in your classpath. add it to your pom and it should work.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version><!--your spring version--></version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: No Jens. It did not work out still. Any more inputs?

Answer (score 0):

In my case only this worked (for executable jar file):

Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Dependency **(same as Jens answer)**:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although its late to answer but let me add my 2 cents, for me all the jars and build plugin were there in pom but scope for the jar was "provided" and hence though it was running through jar it wasn't through my IDE (intelliJ), once commented that working all good.